# how to provide name to an attribute along with value

Tags: xml

hi we want to write xml in which we want to insert

```
<measType p="1">RRC.ConnEstabAtt.Cause</measType>
```

we are using

```
xmlTextWriterWriteFormatElement(writer, BAD_CAST "measType", "%s", "RRC.ConnEstabAtt.Cause");
```

but it simply print output as

```
<measType>RRC.ConnEstabAtt.Cause</measType>
```

Comment: What language and platform are you using? Are we expected to guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using libxml2, and you'll have to use a couple of different instructions to get the attributes in.  (See http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlwriter.html)
Try something like:

```
xmlTextWriterStartElement(writer, "measType");
xmlTextWriterWriteAttribute(writer, "p", "1");
xmlTextWriterWriteString("RRC.ConnEstabAtt.Cause");
xmlTextWriterEndElement(writer);
```

Cheers, Peter.